# Delete columns, not just empty them

Tags: awk, command-line

I'm trying to delete the last 2 columns of a csv file with awk. I have tried using:

```
x=$(awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS=',' '{$10=$11=""; print $0}' ${filename} > nse.csv)
```

But it just deletes the data in the columns not deletes it.

For example if this is the original csv:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

The nse.csv will look like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,
```

Instead of:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this With `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS=',' '{NF-=2} 1' file
```

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Just don’t try this on `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3`.

Comment: Don't do that first one - doing a sub based on the contents of the fields can go wrong in various ways depending on the value of those fields, e.g. duplicates of other earlier fields as @user3840170 points out, or regexp metacharacters. If you were going to do a sub it should be `sub("("OFS"[^"OFS"]){2}$","")`. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: By the way - in shell you don't need to escape double quotes in a single-quote delimited string so you can just write `FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")'`.